# How to design ui for all mobile resolution instead of creating all layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

In android, How to set ui according to mobile resolution Without using layout_large_xhdpi..etc..

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it programmatically by getting the size of the display (see [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)) and then resizing your views accordingly.

But this is gonna be a huge headache and it's simply better to use the simple system provided by default (different layouts and resources for small, medium, large, extra large, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there is any exact way to define layouts depending upon screen resoulution , but other different ways depending on screen width/height can be used like

**res/layout-w600dp/ (for 600dp screen width)**

**res/layout-h1024dp/ (for 1024 screen height)**

[Detailed Description](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)